# Gauge Chart Implementation

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to implement a Gauge Chart that ranges from 0 to 100 and when the value is over 80 it is green, and less than 80 it is red.

1. Insert "Text Area".
2. What HTML code should I write?
3. What JavaScript code should I write?
4. How should I make the value a calculated column?

Thank you so much¡.

Francisco

Be able to make the graph I need.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]. Questions that sound like you are asking us to write some code for you usually don't do well here. Try to solve your problem first, and post your code when you run into problems. Good luck!